# Magento Custom page - Ajax Contact

Tags: php, ajax, magento

I want to have an Ajax Contact form at a Magento custom page (accessed from the menu) and want a mail be sent to the owner whenever anyone fills in the details. Is there a module for this? If not, what's the best way of building this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Follow steps -

1)Create module by Magento module creater. or just call below ajax from your phtml file button action.

2)Write a Controller action in InexController.php file.

```
 public function saveContactDetailsAction() {
    //get details
     $postData  = $this->getRequest()->getParam('data');
   //save data......
    return  "sucess"
   }
```

3) Write ajax code  in your phtml file.

```
   var reloadurl = '<?php echo $this->getUrl('module/index/saveContactDetails'); ?> ';
    new Ajax.Request(reloadurl, { 
        method: 'POST',
        parameters:id='paramater list with &',

        onComplete: function(transport) 
        { //write sucess code here },
        onFailure: function() 
        { 
           //write error code here
        }});
```

Hope this help